# Counting number of domains from unique emails

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with emails, i want to count how many unique domains I have. equal email count 1.

```
email                    suscriber_id
----------------------------------------------
pepe@yahoo.es            1
pepe@yahoo.es            1
jaime@yahoo.es           2
jese@gmail.com           3
pepe@yahoo.es            1
```

If I try this query:

```
SELECT substring(email,LOCATE('@',email),LENGTH (email)) as domain, count(substring(email,LOCATE('@',email),LENGTH (email))) as counter from tracks group by domain";

domain                  counter
----------------------------------------------
yahoo.es                4
gmail.com               1
```

But I want this result:

```
domain                  counter
----------------------------------------------
yahoo.es                2
gmail.com               1
```

Comment: I'm wondering why you have duplicates in your table.

Comment: How about something like `SELECT blaCountbla FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(email) FROM myTable) WHERE bla=bla` Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `COUNT DISTINCT`. And you can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to access the two substrings easily:

```
select 
  substring_index(email, '@', -1) as domain,
  count(distinct substring_index(email, '@', 1)) as counter 
from tracks 
group by substring_index(email, '@', -1);
```

You may find this more readable:

```
select domain, count(distinct account) as counter
from
(
  select 
    substring_index(email, '@', -1) as domain,
    substring_index(email, '@',  1) as account
  from tracks 
) emails
group by domain;
```